# How to find word that contain regex in java

Tags: java, regex

I want to find words (that means whitespace before and after) based upon a search string
for example:

```
String s = "sdaaf fd hgfaaf ghjfada dgffaasdf";
```

and i want to find all the word that contain the String `"aa"`
the answer will be the words:

```
"sdaaf" , "hgfaaf" , "dgffaasdf"
```

Comment: This problem is not a good candidate for regex.

Comment: @Woot4Moo what makes u think tht

Comment: @Fake.It.Til.U.Make.It because there is a more straight forward way of solving the problem.   Regex has its place, but there are more straight forward and simple solutions.  I understand the desire to use regex in some scenarios, but this one is not worth it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't solve this problem via regex, as there is a more direct way to go about it.

```
String phrase = "aa";
String s = "sdaaf fd hgfaaf ghjfada dgffaasdf";  
String[] words = s.split(" ");  
List<String> wordList = new ArrayList<String>();
for(String word : words)  
{  
    if(word.contains(phrase))
    {
       wordList.add(word);
    }  
]
```

Comment: You beat me by few seconds. :(

Comment: @RohitJain it is ok, there is not fastest gun in the west policy here :)

Comment: Yeah of course its not, till your answer makes sense. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
String regex = "(\\w+aaa\\w+)+";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("helaaalo woraaald how are you toaaaday");

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.print(matcher.group() + " ");
}
```

The ouput is: `helaaalo woraaald toaaaday`

You can change the pattern to suite your needs.

Comment: @Woot4Moo You are right, the pattern `(\\w+aaa\\w+)+` works as well.

Answer (score 0):

**Follow these steps sequentially** to get all the words with `"aa"`: -

- Split your string on space - Use [`String#split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) method for this purpose. This will give you a String array, with all the elements separated by space.
- Then iterate over your String array obtained.
- For each element, check whether it contains your sequence `"aa"` - Use [`String#contains`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) method for this purpose.
- For each element, that contains "aa" print them, or you can add them to an [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html), that you would have to create before hand.

Answer (score 0):

This is a complete solution employing a regex that matches each of your words:

```
final String input = "asdf ljh poiu ddaa aad aa", strToMatch = "aa";
final Matcher m = Pattern.compile(
  String.format("\\w*?%s\\w*", Pattern.quote(strToMatch))).matcher(input);
while (m.find()) System.out.println(m.group());
```

Comment: is the \\b necessary?  Could OP not just split on \\w (word)

Comment: True. Will change. But the starting \\b is necessary to ensure that the match starts at the word boundary, isn't it?

Comment: I would be under the impression the function would receive a String.  I.E.  foo (String toProcess, String toMatch).  Which wouldn't require the \\b as far as i know.  Regex isn't my strong suit fwiw

Comment: Checked it, not necessary. I did introduce `Pattern.quote` on the string that is spliced into the pattern.

Comment: Just ran it without the \\b and it works fine.